# How to set Outlook Display Names Globally

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2003, outlook

I've been given a task which is as follows, make sure that Outlook displays users:-

Firstname - CompanyName,

For example, When users get messages within thier outlook, they wish to see the messages as from " David - Bryan Air" or "Kevin - Doyal Mail"

Any tips? Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the "company name" column from the address book to the main display view in Outlook. I think there is a mechanism to push this "view" out to people but I've not had to do something like that in a long time. Now, as for what populates that field? That would take some research. I just added it to mine here and even though I know some of these fields are populated in my address book none of them are showing on the Inbox. You could also manipulate people's display names if they are in the GAL as a contact I suppose.

Comment: I would also point out, mass AD changes should usually be done using a script in PowerShell or perhaps use the tool PowerGUI.